# Xorg Crashes after installing Catalyst

Tags: drivers, ati, xorg, fglrx

I am trying to install the AMD Catalyst, but after reboot I hit a black screen. I checked the `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` and everything is fine up to the point where it has a segmentation fault.

```
[    16.320] (EE) Backtrace:
[    16.320] (EE) 0: /usr/bin/X (xorg_backtrace+0x48) [0x7f760efa8d28]
[    16.320] (EE) 1: /usr/bin/X (0x7f760ee00000+0x1aca19) [0x7f760efaca19]
[    16.320] (EE) 2: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x7f760defd000+0x10340) [0x7f760df0d340]
[    16.320] (EE) 3: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so (0x7f760946c000+0x15660) [0x7f7609481660]
[    16.320] (EE) 4: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so (0x7f760946c000+0x10dfe9) [0x7f7609579fe9]
[    16.320] (EE) 5: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so (0x7f760946c000+0x10e545) [0x7f760957a545]
[    16.321] (EE) 6: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/extra-modules.dpkg-tmp/modules/drivers/fglrx_drv.so (xdl_xs115_atiddxPxScreenInit+0x72) [0x7f7609f30ec2]
[    16.321] (EE) 7: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/extra-modules.dpkg-tmp/modules/drivers/fglrx_drv.so (xdl_xs115_atiddxScreenInit+0x11fa) [0x7f7609f0d7fa]
[    16.321] (EE) 8: /usr/bin/X (AddScreen+0x71) [0x7f760ee55ca1]
[    16.321] (EE) 9: /usr/bin/X (InitOutput+0x3c8) [0x7f760ee96ce8]
[    16.321] (EE) 10: /usr/bin/X (0x7f760ee00000+0x596bb) [0x7f760ee596bb]
[    16.321] (EE) 11: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xf5) [0x7f760c93cec5]
[    16.321] (EE) 12: /usr/bin/X (0x7f760ee00000+0x44dde) [0x7f760ee44dde]
[    16.321] (EE) 
[    16.321] (EE) Segmentation fault at address 0x18
```

Here is the full log: http://paste.ubuntu.com/8868827/

Here is the output of `lshw`: http://paste.ubuntu.com/8869436/

Here is the output of `inxi -Fx`: http://paste.ubuntu.com/8869518/

I have been fighting with fglrx and PowerXpress all day, and this is how far I have got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly it is unsolvable for me. I have a muxed laptop, which means that none of the drivers properly support it.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 14.10 64 bits I faced out the same errors after upgrade. So I performed the following commands and it's working now.

On the console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>)

Uninstall and remove all configuration files:

```
sudo apt-get purge fglrx*
```

Install the proprietary package on Ubuntu repositories:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install fglrx fglrx-amdcccle
```

Create a new xorg.conf

```
sudo aticonfig --initial
```

Restart the PC

```
sudo reboot
```

So, After the system splashscreen, the lightdm greeter must be displayed.

Comment: [Marcos Rocha's solution](http://askubuntu.com/a/546946/396534) worked for me.<br/>
One thing I made different: I used amdconfig instead of aticonfig.<br/> My Setup:<br/>
Ubuntu 14.04 LTS<br/>
HIS Radeon R9 290 IceQ X2 OC<br/>
Intel i5-4570 (with GPU)<br/>
Asrock Fatal1ty H87<br/>

Comment: Just tested it and Marcos is right. Same exact config and after these steps iwth the amdconfig modification everything works wonderfully. Great job.

Answer (score 0):

Also fyi wayland is as of now NOT supported (black screen @ login) on flgrx from upstream or from amd. Because of that if your system has a graphic environment that uses wayland ie gnome 3.14 you must revert to radeonsi (open source driver). The performance is sub par and the driver supports up to OpenGL 3.3 extension, so compatibility is an issue but at least you boot past init 5 :P.

Also I recommend fglrx-update (quite stable) with patches for the newer kernels:

```
sudo apt-get -y purge fglrx*
sudo update-alternatives -y --remove-all x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf
sudo apt-get install --reinstall -y libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx
sudo apt-get -y install fglrx-updates*
```

to reinstall the open source driver just stop at the third command (dont install fglrx-updates)

Comment: I am not running Gnome